# Update documents with $not criteria

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I would like to update with mongoose documents where the criteria **is not** something,
I thought about something like this:

```
Candidate.update({candidateID: $not: {req.body.candidateID} }, {status: 'REJECTED'})
```

I don't think that it would work because `$not` works with `<operator-expression>`..

How can I achieve to update something like this?

Answer (score 0):

In update query, the first part is to documents to be updated, and secand part is to specify the changes to the document given. In you case you have to use the operator $set

```
 Candidate.update({candidateID: $not: {req.body.candidateID} }, {$set:{status: 'REJECTED'}})
```